# How can I apply (Default) my costume settings to any other new user?

Tags: 16.04, customization, selinux

I have Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installed. How can I apply all of my custom settings to any other new user (like themes, icons, custom settings, wallpapers, etc)?

Thanks.